# Как сделать так чтоб бэкенд все присланные данные записал и их можно было запросить фронтендом?

Tags: golang, backend

Есть фронтенд который присылает данные first_name = введённое имя , last_name = введённая фамилия в бэкенд. Как сделать так чтоб бэкенд все присланные данные записал и их можно было запросить фронтендом GET . Только начинаю изучать бэкенд . Не судите строго за код и за знание языка GO .

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
type Response struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}
type Names struct {
    FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}

func postName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        return
    }
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        // check err
    }
    
    var n Names
    
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &n); err != nil {
        // check err
    }
    log.Printf("FirstName: %v , LastName: %v \n", n.FirstName, n.LastName)  // выводит отправленные данные
    res, err := json.Marshal(n)
    if err != nil {
        // check err
    }
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Write(res)  
}

func getName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
    
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Response{Status: "OK"})
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/get",getName).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/post",postName).Methods("POST")

    fmt.Println("Listen and Server")
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:3000"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"})
    credentialsOk := handlers.AllowCredentials()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000" , handlers.CORS(headersOk, originsOk, methodsOk, credentialsOk)(router)))
}
```

Чтобы что то похожее было только состоящее из first_name и last_name
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Куда ты хочешь записать?)
Для тестов, объяви глобальный срез:

```
var names []Names
```

В него добавляй значения из post запроса.

```
func postName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //...
    var n Names
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&n)
    if err != nil {
        // check err
    }
    names = append(names, n)
    //...
}
```

На запрос получения, перебирайешь его, и выводишь нужное.

```
var res []Names
for _, n := range names {
    if n.First_name == "" && n.Last_name == ""{
        res = append(res, n)
    }
}
```